# Лабораторная работа: класс Комплексное число

Tags: c#

Задание
Реализовать класс в соответствии с вариантом задания. Класс 
должен содержать:

1. закрытые неизменяемые поля, хранящие состояние класса;
2. методы для выполнения операций над объектами класса. Эти методы 
   должны применять операцию к текущему объекту (this) и объекту, 
   переданному в качестве аргумента метода. Для представления результата 
   создается новый объект, который и возвращается из метода. При этом ни 
   текущий объект (this), ни объект-аргумент метода не изменяются;
3. свойства, возвращающие атрибуты абстракции, представленной классом;
4. закрытый конструктор, принимающий аргументы — значения полей;
5. статические методы конструирования.
   Экземпляры данного класса должны быть неизменяемыми.
   В консольном приложении требуется продемонстрировать использование 
   разработанного класса.

Нужно создать 
Класс: Комплексное число
Состояние (поля): действительная и мнимая части
Методы конструирования: создание комплексного числа в алгебраической форме, создание 
комплексного числа в тригонометрической форме
Свойства: действительная часть, мнимая часть, модуль, аргумент
Операции: сложение и вычитание

Вот такой у меня код

```
using System;

namespace Complex1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double re, im, mod, arg;
        Console.Write("Введите действительную часть комплексного числа re = ");
        re = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Введите мнимую часть комплексного числа im = ");
        im = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Complex res = new Complex(re, im);
    }
}

public class Complex
{
    public Complex() { }

    public Complex(double _re, double _im)
    {
        re = _re;
        im = _im;
    }

    public Complex(double _mod, double _arg)
    {
        re = _mod * Math.Cos(_arg);
        im = _mod * Math.Sin(_arg);
    }

    public static Complex operator +(Complex num1, Complex num2)
    {
        return new Complex(num1.re + num2.re, num2.im + num2.im);
    }

    public static Complex operator -(Complex num1, Complex num2)
    {
        return new Complex(num1.re - num2.re, num2.im - num2.im);
    }

    public double Re { get; set; }
    public double Im { get; set; }

    private double re, im;
}
}
```

Первый вопрос - у меня получилось два конструктора с одинаковыми сигнатурами, как это решить?
И не понимаю, как мне применить п2. методы для выполнения операций над объектами класса. Эти методы 
должны применять операцию к текущему объекту (this) и объекту, 
переданному в качестве аргумента метода. Для представления результата 
создается новый объект, который и возвращается из метода. При этом ни 
текущий объект (this), ни объект-аргумент метода не изменяются;
Вроде, использование ключевого слова this у меня нигде не обязательно.

и п5. зачем мне тут нужны статические конструкторы?

Comment: @VladD почему я получаю в таком коде http://pastebin.com/80WGPDsZ что комплексные числа нули?

Comment: @Heidel: Потому что вы завели и свойства `Re`, `Im`, и поля `re`, `im`. Вы инициализируете только поля, а свойства как были нулями, так и остаются.

Выкиньте поля полностью, а для свойств запретите модификацию извне:

    public double Re { get; private set; }

Comment: А если у меня по заданию в классе должны быть `закрытые неизменяемые поля, хранящие состояние класса;` ?

Comment: @Heidel: тогда так:

    private readonly double re;
    public double Re { get { return re; } }

---
Возможно, ещё так:

    public double Mod { get { return Math.Sqrt(re * re + im * im); } }
    public double Arg { get { return Math.Atan2(im, re); } }

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Heidel: пожалуйста!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

По поводу одинаковых конструкторов: примените фабричный метод!

```
public class Complex
{
    public Complex() { }

    private Complex(double _re, double _im)
    {
        re = _re;
        im = _im;
    }

    public static Complex FromCartesian(double _re, double _im)
    {
        return new Complex(_re, _im);
    }

    public static Complex FromPolar(double _mod, double _arg)
    {
        var re = _mod * Math.Cos(_arg);
        var im = _mod * Math.Sin(_arg);
        return new Complex(re, im);
    }

    // ...
```

Вы в принципе правильно написали оператор сложения, но задание требует использования нестатического метода, поэтому попробуйте так:

```
    public Complex operator + (Complex num2)
    {
        return new Complex(this.re + num2.re, this.im + num2.im);
    }
```

Кстати, у вас там была опечатка: вместо `num2.im + num2.im` надо бы `num1.im + num2.im` (и то же самое в вычитании).

Update: перегруженные операторы сложения должны быть статическими, так не пойдёт. Либо оставляйте как есть, либо замените `operator +` на нестатический метод `Add`.

В п. 5 у вас не статические конструкторы, а статические *методы конструирования*. Здесь имеются в виду как раз методы типа `FromPolar`: они статические, и создают объект, то есть, используются вместо конструктора. (Это ещё называется идиомой «именованного конструктора»).

Comment: Можете объяснить как это работает?

Comment: Вообще-то, оно не работает.

Comment: @Heidel: «оно не работает» — бесполезное описание проблемы. Опишите, что вы делаете, что ожидаете, и что видите на самом деле.

Comment: Ваш оператор сложения не работает  `public static Complex operator +(Complex num2)
  {
   return new Complex(this.re + num2.re, this.im + num2.im);
  }`  Can't use 'this' in static methos

Comment: @Heidel: во-первых, «не компилируется», во-вторых, у меня нету `static`, а у вас есть.

Comment: А где в задании указано, что операторы сложения-вычитания должны быть нестатическими?

Comment: @Heidel: И правда, так нельзя. Тогда или оставьте как было `static` с двумя аргументами, или сделайте из этого метод:

    public Complex Add(Complex that)
    {
        return new Complex(this.re + that.re, this.im + that.im);
    }

(но тогда вы не сможете использовать сложение символом `+`).

По поводу нестатических методов сказано в задании:

> Эти методы должны применять операцию к текущему объекту (this) и объекту, переданному в качестве аргумента метода